# How to do get the sum and average of cells from different raster data with the same extent, projection and resolution using terra::app, R

Tags: r, terra

At first I read all the tif with the name of 2000. Second, I crop the tifs into the same extent, and coordination. Third, I need to do the anlysis to know the sum and average of cells values from the tifs (8 layers), I know that the function of terra::app or rapp, however, I have no idea how to run it, because of the parameters of 'start' and 'end'.
Finally, I would like to get a rast for the sum and average cells values.

```
tif <- list.files(path = "Pop", pattern = "*2000.tif",full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
tifs <- trim(mask(rast(tif), shp)) %>% project(crs(pp))
rstart <- rast(tifs, nlyr =1)
rend <- rast(tifs, nlyr =8)
r <- c(rstart, rend)
TIF <- rapp(tifs, r, "sum")
TIF <- rapp(tifs, r, "mean")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sum` and `mean` methods

```
library(terra)
tifs <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))   
s <- sum(tifs)
m <- mean(tifs)
```

or the equivalent

```
ss <- app(tifs, sum)
mm <- app(tifs, mean)
```